# Find out how many users can be online at the same time?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a server where I want to put my website, Is there a formula to calculate the maximum number of users can be online at the same time?

Technologies: ASP.NET MVC, C#, SQL Server.

Number Of CPU Cores: 12.

Comment: The only real way to know is test. Use a load simulation tool to generate a lot of traffic.

Comment: I believe there is no such formula. If there were, Google should tell you immediately.

Comment: you know this when you measure the TTFB time of your website. does it load in < 10ms? then it can handle hundreds of simultaneous users. does it load in < 100 ms, then it can still handle 100 users that dont click too much at the same time. does it load in more than a sec? then it can probably handle only a few users.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of approaches available to test your server balancing. I would suggest you to use some scripts and that will create number of users and logged your application at the same time to know real time testing experince.

Below are few tools which create test scripts and load-test your site.

- [**JMeter**](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) - A JMeter script can simulate a typical end-user by opening the front page first, waiting for some seconds, opening a new page etc. JMeter may run several scripts to simulate many end-users and will constantly report reponse times, success rate etc.
- [**Load Impact**](https://loadimpact.com/)  - it simulates users on your site and slowly increases the number of simulated users on your site as the test runs. It does offer a free test as well, and shows you the load time for your files as the number of users increases.

*Point to be noted: Remember that your own internet connection may also be a bottleneck when load testing.*

Comment: Thank you, But my website is not ready and I need to know this before preparing

Comment: Please visit https://aionhill.com/how-many-users-can-your-online-store-handle-simultaneously and it will guide you the prerequisite things